# Prevent tomcat from starting application on deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Is there any way to tell Tomcat not to automatically start application which I want to deploy? I'd like to this manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" 
    xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">
```

Note the `autoDeploy="false"`

Comment: This only disables auto-deploying of new applications and auto-redeploying of existing applications. But already deployed applications are still automatically started.

Answer (score 3):

I understand your question as not deploying your app on starting Tomcat - if so,

At the `<Host>` in `server.xml`, `deployOnStartup` attribute set to `false` should do it.

But that will affect all webapps on that server. The default is true

Comment: Not exactly. I have tomcat running and then deploy application and I don't want this application to start when it's finished deploying.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, since at least Tomcat 7.0 every container has an undocumented property `startChildren` (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/6776cb6f3213af953ec350f37084c6370acf3732/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase.java#L251)), which decides whether children should be automatically started.

Setting:

```xml
<Host startChildren="false" />
```

will prevent auto-deployed applications to start automatically.

**Remark**: this only applies to auto-deployed applications (i.e. those added to the `StandardHost` after it already started). The applications configured in `server.xml` will start automatically, when the `StandardHost` starts.

Comment: I think this is the only answer which attempts to answer the exact question so +1 for that.  It's not what I was looking for though so I can't evaluate its correctness.