# How to deploy only a specific project in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I set up quite a few projects in the same tomcat server by adding contexts files in \conf\Catalina\localhost\ and .war files in a custom folder. Everything actually works fine, but I have to run all of the projects at once. Or by removing all of the contexts from the localhost directory (and adding only one that I need) I could start just the needed one. Is there a way to keep all of the projects in the same folder and just tell tomcat which one to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When auto-deploying applications from the host's `xmlBase` directory (`\conf\Catalina\localhost` in your case) Tomcat **ignores** all files without the `.xml` extensions. Therefore you can rename all files to prevent their deployment.

If, however, you want to deploy all projects, but don't start them, you can proceed as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4132182/11748454) by adding `startChildren="false"` to your host.

If you choose the second solution starting your application becomes tricky: you need to configure Tomcat Manager in the `server.xml` file, so that it starts with the system and you can start the other application through it. Just copy the contents of `webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml` into the `<Host>` element and add the `path` and `docBase` attributes:

```xml
<Host>
  <Context path="/manager" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager" antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
    <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor"
                     sameSiteCookies="strict" />
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
    <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
  </Context>
  ...
</Host>
```

Comment: Btw do you have any suggestions on how to start manager on tomcat start?

Comment: @aratata: I added the instructions to the answer.